# Kibana 3: how to get an average?

Tags: elasticsearch, average, kibana

Assume I have the following events in a specified time span:

```
1: e1
2: e2
3: e2
4: e2
5: e3
6: e3
7: e3
8: e3
9: e3
```

I want them in a chart appearing like this:

```
e1 x 1
e2 x 3
e3 x 5
```

and I an average calculated like this:

```
(count(e1) + count(e2) + count(e3)) / number_of_different_events = (1+3+5)/3 = 3
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Kibana 3, but in Kibana 4 you can create a "Metric Visualization" and average is an option:

[image]